# Объединение условий

Tags: python, python-3.x, условия

```py
x = float(input())

if x >= 582.5 and x <= 582.5 and x >= 582.5:
    print('3 u')
elif x >= 482.5 and x:
    print('2 u')
```

Как правильнее объединить эти условия?:

`x <= 582.5 and x >= 582.5`

Comment: Странные условия x >= 582.5 and **x <=582.5 and x >= 582.5** Судя по этим условиям x может быть больше/меньше/равен 582.5. Что же все таки надо сделать?

Comment: вообще больше похоже на выборку по словарю. Тогда проще сделать так:
```
if x == 582.5:
  print('3 u')
elif x == 482.5:
  print('2u')
else:
  assert x > 0
```

Comment: Напишите словами, что именно вы хотите проверить?

Comment: Что имеете ввиду под "объединить эти условия". Вы хотите что-бы число было равно и было больше и одновременно меньше чем условие? Тогда Вам явно нужно в 4-е измерение.

Comment: Может вы условия задачи все же напишете в вопросе? Есть подозрение что вы ее не правильно поняли.

Comment: Кажется, забыли добавить `and x <= 582.5`.

Answer (score 2):

```
x <= 582.5 and x >= 582.5
```

значит просто, что

```
x == 582.5
```